# d3.js cinemetrics animation based chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, d3.js

I've developed a kind of cinemetrics based chart using d3.js. I've added a spectrum of data to control a motion speed, but there appears to be a conflict with tweening animation between different data updates and the segment animations.

1. the tweening and motion animations conflict - if its possible to add a transition end callback to trigger the motion animations.
2. potential to create a colour gradient/colour strips as opposed to full filled segments

[image]

[image]

https://vimeo.com/26584083

The latest code
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/217/

```
 spike: function () {
        //console.log("spike ready", data);

        var that = this;
       var timeScale = d3.scale.linear()
           .domain([1, 5])
           .range([900,3500, 8000]) //larger movement values have smaller durations
           ;

        function throb(d, i) {

            var dur = timeScale(d.movement);

            var p = d3.select(this);

            if (!p.classed("moving") ) {
                p.transition()
                    .duration(dur)
                    .attr("d", that.getArc(-5))
                .transition()
                    .duration(dur)
                    .attr("d", that.getArc(+5))
                    .each("end", throb);
            }
        }

       //The spike function *returns* the throb function so it can be used in
       // an each call:
       return throb;

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a base pattern - that can be used to apply a gradient to the segments. Ideally I want the segments to look like stripes as opposed to a smooth blend. Also want to be able to build the patterns accordingly with the colour array coming from the data json.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/371/

I'd like to ensure the gradient is from top to bottom - so for example the inner section is red, the outer section green. Also stripped as opposed to a smooth blend.

[image]

here is the code for the pattern

```
<svg>
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="matrixLinearGradient"
                                    x1="0%" y1="0%"
                                    x2="100%" y2="100%"
                                    spreadMethod="pad">
      <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#00cc00" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#cc0000" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

also looked at this method to, but not sure if its the way to go or not.
http://jsfiddle.net/Y2zue/

Comment: Here is a gradient demo - to see if that will create the correct effect - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/371/

Comment: Used a gradient transform here to get it 90 degrees - http://jsfiddle.net/qsBPm/1/

Comment: adding a create gradient pattern into the system - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/375/

Comment: ok its using the gradient function now - but similar issue - where the pattern segments are not curving with the chart - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/376/

Comment: I've tried to rotate the gradient angle along with the segment index. Need to get the ratio correct. Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/378/

Answer (score 0):

Tackling just the gradient issue first.

[image]
This is a stripped down barebones example - a pie chart, 3 data sets, gradient builder.

I am trying to get the gradient to angle itself towards the center as it is built for each segment. So it looks more like the right image, than its current left.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/437/

here is the code

I've supplied the segment index and the number of segments in total. I am not sure though how this information can be used effectively to tweak the gradient angle so it mimics the right image demo.

```
createGradient(sliceindex, segmentCount){

            var svg = d3.select(".patterns")

            var rotateAngle = sliceindex*4;

            var gradient = svg.append("svg:defs")
              .append("svg:linearGradient")
                .attr("id", "gradient"+sliceindex)
                .attr("x1", "0%")
                .attr("x2", "100%")
                .attr("y1", "50%")    
                .attr("y2", "50%")
                .attr("spreadMethod", "pad")
                .attr("gradientTransform", "rotate("+rotateAngle+")")

                gradient.append("svg:stop")
                    .attr("offset", "0%")
                    .attr("stop-color", "#0c0")
                    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);

                gradient.append("svg:stop")
                    .attr("offset", "40%")
                    .attr("stop-color", "#ff9f00")
                    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);


                gradient.append("svg:stop")
                    .attr("offset", "70%")
                    .attr("stop-color", "#d500af")
                    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);


                gradient.append("svg:stop")
                    .attr("offset", "100%")
                    .attr("stop-color", "#c00")
                    .attr("stop-opacity", 1);        
}
```

Comment: I've managed to get the pink to match in 2 segments - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/443/